# Triggering a function with clicking on compose button

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I wonder If it is possible to run a function as clicking on the [compose or reply buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLQT7.png). My updateDraft function runs as clicking on the [add-on button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXgV1.png) in compose window but I couldn't find any information in documentation, about running a function just after clicking on the compose button.

```
   "composeTrigger": {
      "selectActions": [{
        "text": "Insert Image",
        "runFunction": "updateDraft"
      }],
      "draftAccess": "METADATA"
    }
```

[image: compose or reply buttons]

[image: add-on button]

Comment: The Card Service despite some complexities brought on by its simplicity (!) is very cool. However as a `composeTrigger` it's very limited. You can't even get access to the message you're replying to. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176416923

Answer (score 1):

The only access that Gmail Addons have to Gmail is through the Card Service.  So if you can't find it in the card service then you don't have it.

[Card Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service)